# The beginning and end address of the Flash memory

Tags: linux, boot, openwrt, u-boot, flash-memory

I am trying to run Linux on an Arduino Yun board. The Arduino board contains an [Atheros AR9331 chipset](https://www.openhacks.com/uploadsproductos/ar9331_datasheet.pdf)

On U-Boot these are the steps I am doing:

1- Download the kernel:

```
ar7240> tftp 0x80060000 openwrt-ar71xx-generic-uImage-lzma.bin;
Load address: 0x80060000
Loading: #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     ######################
done
Bytes transferred = 1441863 (160047 hex)
```

2- Erase Flash in order to copy the kernel:

```
ar7240> erase 0x9fEa0000 +0x160047 
Error: end address (0xa0000046) not in flash!
Bad address format
```

This is the problem It seems that `0x9fEa0000 +0x160047` exceeds the total size of the flash.

So my questions are:

1- How can I figure the total amount of memory reserved for the flash in Uboot (From which address it starts and ends), I am thinking about changing `0x9fEa0000` by a fewer address but I'm afraid I can harm other things

This is the output of the help:

```
ar7240> help
?       - alias for 'help'
boot    - boot default, i.e., run 'bootcmd'
bootd   - boot default, i.e., run 'bootcmd'
bootm   - boot application image from memory
cp      - memory copy
erase   - erase FLASH memory
help    - print online help
md      - memory display
mm      - memory modify (auto-incrementing)
mtest   - simple RAM test
mw      - memory write (fill)
nm      - memory modify (constant address)
ping    - send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST to network host
printenv- print environment variables
progmac - Set ethernet MAC addresses
reset   - Perform RESET of the CPU
run     - run commands in an environment variable
setenv  - set environment variables
tftpboot- boot image via network using TFTP protocol
version - print monitor version
```

2- Is there someone experienced with [Atheros AR9331 chipset](https://www.openhacks.com/uploadsproductos/ar9331_datasheet.pdf)  who can help me find the Flash mapping (From where it starts and ends) from the datasheet

Comment: Apparently, flash is mapped to 0x9f000000 and it is 16 MB. Flash layout is either hardcoded in U-Boot or specified in the U-boot script or parameter area, also on flash. Before the kernel image, there is likely the root filesystem. Is there any output from `printenv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the flash layout from the kernel boot command line. Either run the `printenv` command in u-boot or boot into the existing kernel and look through the boot log. You need to find something like the following:

(There are plenty of guides on the internet, I took this one from https://finninday.net/wiki/index.php/Arduino_yun, your board may or may not be the same).

```
linino> printenv
bootargs=console=ttyATH0,115200 board=linino-yun mem=64M rootfstype=squashfs,jffs2 noinitrd mtdparts=spi0.0:256k(u-boot)ro,64k(u-boot-env)ro,14656k(rootfs),1280k(kernel),64k(nvram),64k(art),15936k@0x50000(firmware)
bootcmd=bootm 0x9fea0000
```

This means there are the following partitions:

```
u-boot 0 to 256K (0x0 - 0x40000)
u-boot-env 256k to 320k (0x40000 - 0x50000)
rootfs (squashfs) 320k to 14976k (0x50000 - 0xea0000)
kernel 14976k to 16256k (0xea0000 - 0xfe0000)
nvram 16256k to 16320k (0xfe0000 - 0xff0000)
art 16320k to 16384k (0xff0000 - 0x1000000)
```

The rootfs partition is 14M, which is much larger than the rootfs image file (less than 8MB) so in theory you can move the kernel image at a lower address. For this you will need to modify the kernel boot line in the u-boot environment block (`rootfs` aand `kernel` partition sizes) and the `bootcmd` parameter so the u-boot know where the new kernel is located.

Flash is mapped to `0x9f000000` so the value in the `bootcmd` should be  `0x9f000000` + the offset of the kernel in bytes.

What I am not sure about is if there is an overlay filesystem for any persistent changes to the flash. Can you boot into the existing system and post the output of `df -h` and `cat /proc/mounts`?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, could you please explain how "Flash is mapped to 0x9f000000", I can't find this value in the Datasheet.

Comment: I don't know. How  SPI flash is accessed through the memory interface is not in the datasheet. The value 0x9f000000 appears in the u-boot config file and the device tree file for AP121 and AP143 reference boards, that use the AR933x chip (e.g. http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=board/qca/ap121/Kconfig, http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/mips/dts/ap121.dts)

Comment: Got it Thank you